# Drawing lines between countries on pre-defined Robinson map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, line, spatial

I have a specific map to which I'd like to add lines between countries, and later on, also line weights. The code below runs, but nothing shows up on the map. Note that `df`  is created with `ne_countries()`, but I `st_transform` the map to Robinson projection, so I'm not sure the coordinates of df are correct.

I know there are many ways of drawing lines on a map, and I'm not sure geom_segment is the best so I'm open to other solutions. I'm fine with adding points and then lines, which I've seen but also couldn't make work.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)

#creating the map:

# Download countries polygons
shp <- ne_countries(type = "countries", 
                    scale = "medium",
                    returnclass = "sf") |>
  # transform to desired projection
  st_transform("ESRI:54030")

shp <- subset(shp, select = -c(1:17, 19:63))

# Creating df with long and lat

countries <- ne_countries()

countries$longitude <- coordinates(countries)[,1]

countries$latitude <- coordinates(countries)[,2]

countries_xy <- countries@data %>%
  select(admin, longitude, latitude)


# Joining long and lat to origin & destination

df1 <- tibble(origins = sample(c('Australia'), 
                                  size = 1, replace = TRUE), 
                 destinations = sample(c('Fiji', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Sweden'), 
                                       size = 3, replace = FALSE))

df2 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(countries_xy, by = c('origins' = 'admin')) %>%
  left_join(countries_xy, by = c('destinations' = 'admin'))

df2$longitude.y <- as.numeric(as.character(df3$longitude.y))

df2$latitude.y <- as.numeric(as.character(df3$latitude.y))

# Merging shp and df

shp <- merge(shp,df2, by = "name", all.x = TRUE)

# Drawing the lines on the map (note that I also color the map with a discrete variable, but I don't think that is important here)

shp |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = discrete_var)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = latitude.x, 
                   y = latitude.y,
                   xend = longitude.x,
                   yend = longitude.y), 
               color = "white") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Purples', direction=-1, na.value="grey", drop = FALSE) +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)
```

I know there are many other ways of drawing lines on a map, and I'm not sure `geom_segment` is the best so I'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is way easier to plot and analyse spatial data if they are all spatial objects (sf, sfc, SpatRaster etc.). So here's a method to create your lines as an sf object.

It was not clear from your code where you wanted the lines to terminate so I have arbitrarily used country centroids for this example. It is possible to use `st_nearest_points()` if you want, but I believe centroids are a better choice visually for what you are mapping. Comment below if you want the lines to terminate in a different location.

Also, you do not need to explicitly load the `rgdal` library as `sf` binds to it `GDAL` by default. Further, `rgdal` was deprecated last year and it's functions are being passed to `sf`. For example, functions like `coordinates()` can be handled by `sf` as `st_coordinates()`.

**EDIT:** Based on OP's comments, if you have previously installed `rgdal`, you may need to remove all traces of it from your library directory. That includes the versions of `GDAL`, `GEOS`, and `PROJ` that `rgdal` binds to. The answer was also updated as the OP requested a curved geom, hence the inclusion of the x1, x2, y1, and y2 columns.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)

# Create world map in Robinson projection
countries <- ne_countries() %>%
  st_transform("ESRI:54030")

# Subset countries of interest and add lines between Australia and the rest
sf_line <- countries %>%
  select(admin) %>%
  filter(admin %in% c("Australia", "Fiji", "Papua New Guinea", "Sweden")) %>%
  mutate(to = st_centroid(geometry)) %>%
  st_set_geometry("to") %>%
  select(-geometry) %>%
  mutate(from = to[admin == "Australia"],
         line_geom = st_union(to, from, by_feature = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(!admin == "Australia") %>%
  st_set_geometry("line_geom") %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(x1 = st_coordinates(from)[,1],
         y1 = st_coordinates(from)[,2],
         x2 = st_coordinates(to)[,1],
         y2 = st_coordinates(to)[,2])

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = countries, colour = "grey50") +
  geom_curve(data = sf_line, 
             aes(x = x1, y = y1, 
                 xend = x2, yend = y2), 
             colour = "#CD0BBC",
             arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.03, "npc"), type="closed")) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! But ```countries <- ne_countries() %>%
  st_transform("ESRI:54030")``` gives me ```Error in UseMethod("st_transform") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_transform' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')". ``` The centroids work fine, but wondering if it's possible to curve the lines and add arrows?

Comment: @MoonS - updated to include individual x/y values for `ggeom_curve()`. This is a basic example but SO has a number of answers demonstrating what you can do with `geom_curve()` and arrows etc. And that error indicates your countries object is not an `sf` object and is actually an `sp` object. Try starting a new session and only load the packages as listed in my solution. Also ensure your versions of R and the packages are up to date. Thanks

Comment: @L Tyrone I have updated my R and R studio version and packages and run ```class(countries)```, which returns```sf dataframe```. Even when I run ```countries = st_as_sf(countries)``` and then ```countries <- ne_countries() %>%
+   st_transform("ESRI:54030")```, I get 
```Error in UseMethod("st_transform") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_transform' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')"```. What could be wrong?

Comment: I got it to work with ```countries <- st_transform(countries, crs = "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")```. But when trying to create ```sf_line```, I get ```Error in `stopifnot()`:
ℹ In argument: `line_geom = st_union(to, from, by_feature = TRUE)`.
Caused by error:
! `line_geom` must be size 4 or 1, not 16.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.```

Comment: @MoonS - I am almost entirely certain that `rgdal` is to blame, and more precisely, its versions of `GDAL`, `GEOS` and `PROJ`. Given the `ne_countries()` function worked with the older style CRS string, this is the most likely cause. There are a number of [related questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/238497/35239) regarding `rgdal`. 1) run `sf_extSoftVersion()` and check if you have `GEOS 3.11.2`, `GDAL 3.7.2`,  `proj.4 9.3.0`, `GDAL_with_GEOS = true`, `USE_PROJ_H = true`, and `PROJ 9.3.0` in your envirionment.

Comment: 2) In relation to your second issue, this is being caused by the first issue. Your countries object is being created as a "POLYGON" geometry type instead of the default "MULTIPOLYGON". If you run `countries <- st_transform(countries, crs = "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") %>% st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON")`, does the code work? But this still doesn't resolve the first issue. Given `rgdal` is now deprecated, I'd purge it, unless you have old code that relies on it.

Comment: 3) What OS are you using? A number of OSX users report similar issues. If the above does not solve your issue, you'll have to open a new question outlining the problem you're having. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256955/discussion-between-moons-and-l-tyrone).