# Why can't I cut a buffer, both in R and QGIS?

Tags: dplyr, buffer, qgis, geosphere, epsg

My question is very straightforward.
I am working with a large coordinates dataset (animal GPS tracks). I would like to create a buffer of a 50km radius around the point where all my tracks start.

No matter what I do, there's something wrong with the CRS and the buffer ends up being in a different place or completely out of scale and not centered on the said point. My QGIS project is EPSG:32632, my tracks are visible only as Point-EPSG:4326. My buffer, on the other hand, ends up at the Equator.

I'm now trying to do it in R. My df is called codoni, I'll attach the str.

codoni df str:

```
> str(codoni)
'data.frame':   149366 obs. of  8 variables:
$ id      : chr  "N34246@096AFE12" "N34246@096AFE12" "N34246@096AFE12"
"N34246@096AFE12" ...
$ DateTime: POSIXct, format: "2022-02-23 03:36:00" "2022-02-23 05:36:00" "2022-02-23
07:36:00" "2022-02-23 09:36:00" ...
$ lat     : num  45.5 45.5 45.5 45.5 45.5 ...
 $ lon     : num  12.6 12.6 12.6 12.6 12.6 ...
$ Altitude: int  0 0 0 6 0 9 0 82 0 0 ...
$ Sex     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Age     : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
$ Tag     : chr  "GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART" "GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART" "GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART"
"GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART" ...
```

I managed to avoid all error messages but unfortunately, my buffer still ends up being in a completely wrong location. This is why my codoni_clipped ends up being empty (and also why instead of using the codoni_clipped in the ggplot, as I would want to do, I am using the codoni_sf).
This is my code:

```
cavallino <- c(45.501518, 12.565928) 
cavallino_point <- st_sfc(st_point(cavallino))
st_crs(cavallino_point) <- 4326
# buffer around cavallino in EPSG:4326
buffer_4326 <- st_buffer(cavallino_point, dist = 50000)
st_crs(buffer_4326) <- st_crs(4326)
buffer_32632 <- st_transform(buffer_4326, 32632)
st_geometry(buffer_32632)
st_crs(buffer_32632)
# clip tracks to the extent of the buffer
codoni_sf <- st_as_sf(codoni, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs =
4326) %>% st_transform(32632)
st_crs(codoni_sf)
codoni_clipped <- st_intersection(codoni_sf, buffer_32632)
st_geometry(codoni_clipped)
st_crs(codoni_clipped)
# plot tracks and buffer together
final_plot <- ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = codoni_sf, color = "red", size = 0.7) +
geom_sf(data = buffer_32632, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.3) +
labs(title = "Tracks and Buffer (50km radius)",
x = "Longitude",
y = "Latitude") +
theme_minimal()
print(final_plot)
```

Here's the result:

```
> dput(head(codoni, 5)) 
structure(list(id = c("N34246@096AFE12", "N34246@096AFE12",
"N34246@096AFE12", 
"N34246@096AFE12", "N34246@096AFE12"), DateTime =
structure(c(1645583760, 
1645590960, 1645598160, 1645605360, 1645612560), class 
c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), lat = c(45.504295, 45.50255, 45.50186,
45.5025867, 45.5005833), lon = c(12.5623333, 12.566, 12.56615,
12.56315, 12.5618667), Altitude = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L), Sex 
c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Age = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Tag = c("GPS
-GSM_TECHNOSMART", 
"GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART", "GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART", "GPS
GSM_TECHNOSMART", 
"GPS-GSM_TECHNOSMART")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class =
"data.frame")
```

This is my graph, tracks in red, buffer as a small lilac dot on the right. Obviously in the wrong spot (should be around where the tracks start) but correct shape and size.

[image: My ggplot]

What's wrong???

Thank you :)

Comment: You are not projecting your data, you are just telling R that the lon/lat values are in a certain CRS. For instance, if you assign EPSG:32632 to WGS84 values, you are saying those decimal degree values are actually meters. To project your data, you need to set the correct CRS for the values and then use `st_transform()`. For example, `codoni_sf <- st_as_sf(codoni, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% st_transform(32632)`.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I still have issues though, as the buffer appears to be in a totally different location to where it is supposed to be. I'll add the info below.

Comment: Run `dput(head(codoni, 5))` and add the result to your question. That will help diagnose your issue. If that proves too large to copy, reduce that to`dput(head(codoni, 1))`.

Comment: Done! I edited my initial question with the result

Comment: Solved. Can confirm you have your  lon/lat values inverted for one of your datasets. Note the lat values in your `dput()` are in the 45 degrees range. Conversely, for the point coordinates you use to create your buffer, the lon values are in the 45 degrees range. As I don't know which coordinates may be switched, check both unprotected data - e.g. the 4326 - are plotting where your expect them to be. In other words, plot them with a reference map like the `ne_countries()` dataset from the `rnaturalearth` package.

Comment: The first lines of code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78037658/2530121) shows how to create a world map using the `rnaturalearth` package. My guess: it is the way you are creating your cavallino point that is at fault.